# « Rejeter le moucheron et avaler le chameau », est-ce courant ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, religion

Peut-on utiliser couramment l'expression

> Rejeter le moucheron et avaler le chameau.

pour quelqu'un qui évite de petites fautes mais s’en permet de grandes ?

Comment: Je doute qu'elle soit communément comprise. Je ne l'ai personnellement jamais entendue.

Comment: Où l'as-tu trouvée? J'avoue ne jamais l'avoir entendue non plus...

Comment: @LaurentS. Ça vient de la Bible. Évangile selon St-Matthieu, chapitre 23, verset 24. Guides aveugles ! Vous filtrez le moucheron, et vous avalez le chameau ! En grec on l'utilise souvent.

Comment: @LaurentS. https://www.wordreference.com/gren/%CE%B4%CE%B9%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%AF%CE%B6%CF%89%20%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BD%20%CE%BA%CF%8E%CE%BD%CF%89%CF%80%CE%B1

Comment: @LaurentS Donc j'ai cherché la version française ; je l'ai utilisée durant une réunion mais nul m'a compris:-)!

Comment: Ca n'est pas vraiment surprenant, je vois dans les réponses que je ne suis pas le seul à l'entendre pour la première fois. Je n'arrive cependant pas à trouver une expression idiomatique équivalente...

Comment: Voir aussi en [italien](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_des_proverbes_(Quitard)/chameau) ?

Comment: Selon les circonstances, on peut penser à deux expressions plus courantes et qui dénoncent aussi une hypocrisie dans des jugements peu impartiaux: *faire deux poids, deux mesures* ou *la paille et la poutre* (qui vient aussi de la Bible, mais qui a fait sa place dans le français courant).

Comment: @Greg j'avais pensé à celles-là également, mais si je comprends bien l'idée de l'expression d'origine, celle-ci se focalise sur la notion d'incohérence ("c'est très mauvais de ne pas petit-déjeuner, dit-il en s'allumant une cigarette") alors que les 2 autres expressions me semble se baser sur l'injustice ou la discrimination vis à vis d'un autre intervenant...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C'est une expression qu'on retrouve dans le Nouveau Testament (Évangile selon St-Matthieu, chapitre 23, verset 24) :

> Guides aveugles ! Vous filtrez le moucheron, et vous avalez le chameau !

Personnellement je ne l'ai jamais entendue dans le langage courant ni vu réemployée à l'écrit en dehors d'une référence à ce passage.

Comment: Merci ! J'ai connu l'orginine. En grec on l'utilise souvent https://www.wordreference.com/gren/%CE%B4%CE%B9%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%AF%CE%B6%CF%89%20%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BD%20%CE%BA%CF%8E%CE%BD%CF%89%CF%80%CE%B1

Answer (score 3):

Je doute qu'elle soit communément comprise. Je ne l'ai personnellement jamais entendue.

---

Google Ngram donne très peu d'occurrences pour [Avaler le chameau](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avaler+le+chameau&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavaler%20le%20chameau%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cavaler%20le%20chameau%3B%2Cc0)

et aucune occurrence pour [rejeter le moucheron](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rejeter+le+moucheron&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)

*on ne peut pas combiner les deux expressions dans une recherche unique*

Comment: Avec d'autres expressions: [avaler ...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avaler+le+chameau%2Cavaler+des+couleuvres%2Cavaler+de+travers%2Cavaler+sa+langue%2Cavaler+la+route&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavaler%20le%20chameau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavaler%20des%20couleuvres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavaler%20de%20travers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavaler%20sa%20langue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavaler%20la%20route%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

Non, personne ne comprendrait l'expression.

On retrouve un peu cette idée et aussi une origine biblique dans les phrases opposant paille et poutre dans un œil:

> [Voir la paille dans l’œil du voisin mais pas la poutre dans le sien.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voir_la_paille_dans_l%E2%80%99%C5%93il_du_voisin_et_ne_pas_voir_la_poutre_dans_le_sien)

Comment: Effectivement l'idée est similaire, mais s'applique dans la relation entre 2 entités. Par analogie je dirais "Rejeter le moucheron du voisin mais avaler son propre chameau" mais je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit le sens de l'expression d'origine...

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement je ne l'ai jamais lue ni entendue. Je pense qu'elle n'est presque jamais utilisée.